# Edit and Continue on GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb, edit-and-continue

I know that E&C is a controversial subject and some say that it encourages a wrong approach to debugging, but still - I think we can agree that there are numerous cases when it is clearly useful - experimenting with different values of some constants, redesigning GUI parameters on-the-fly to find a good look... You name it.

My question is: **Are we ever going to have E&C on GDB?** I understand that it is a platform-specific feature and needs some serious cooperation with the compiler, the debugger and the OS *(MSVC has this one easy as the compiler and debugger always come in one package)*, but... It still should be doable. I've even heard something about Apple having it implemented in their version of GCC <sup>[citation needed]</sup>. And I'd say it is indeed feasible.

Knowing all the hype about MSVC's E&C (my experience says it's the first thing MSVC users mention when asked *"why not switch to Eclipse and gcc/gdb"*), I'm seriously surprised that after quite some years GCC/GDB still doesn't have such feature. Are there any good reasons for that? Is someone working on it as we speak?

Comment: A real answer isn't possible here, it would be massive flame and downvote bait.  Try programmers.se and ask about leadership roles in the foss world.

Comment: Hans, I sincerely don't understand your remark. I believe my question is rather well-formed: it's a specific question about a popular toolchain and a well-known debugger feature; I'd like to know whether there are any important technical road blocks stopping people from implementing E&C in gcc/gdb and and whether there has already been any known work on implementing it.

Comment: Heh.  I never use E&C but I still find visual Studio much better than Eclipse or any other GCC/GDB based combo.  This is totally due to the tight integration between editor and debugger and I prefer the way the interface is quite lightweight (unless you choose to use hte heavier weight features).  No other IDE is as easily usable or clean interfaced in my opinion.  As such I use VStudio for developing WITH GCC and various other platforms.

Comment: @Goz, it's a matter of taste and requirements. I prefer "powerful" over "lightweight", VC++ EE lacked quite a bit from what I was used to when I've last used it. But let's not start this discussion here.

Comment: Absoloutely I don't disagree ... I'm just pointing out that E&C is not the be all and end all :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a surprisingly non-trivial amount of work, encompassing many design decisions and feature tradeoffs.  Consider: you are debugging.  The debugee is suspended.  Its image in memory contains the object code of the source, and the binary layout of objects, the heap, the stacks.  The debugger is inspecting its memory image.  It has loaded debug information about the symbols, types, address mappings, pc (ip) to source correspondences.  It displays the call stack, data values.

Now you want to allow a particular set of possible edits to the code and/or data, without stopping the debuggee and restarting.  The simplest might be to change one line of code to another.  Perhaps you recompile that file or just that function or just that line.  Now you have to patch the debuggee image to execute that new line of code the next time you step over it or otherwise run through it.  How does that work under the hood?  What happens if the code is larger than the line of code it replaced?  How does it interact with compiler optimizations?  Perhaps you can only do this on a specially compiled for EnC debugging target.  Perhaps you will constrain possible sites it is legal to EnC.  Consider: what happens if you edit a line of code in a function suspended down in the call stack.  When the code returns there does it run the original version of the function or the version with your line changed?  If the original version, where does that source come from?

Can you add or remove locals?  What does that do to the call stack of suspended frames?  Of the current function?

Can you change function signatures?  Add fields to / remove fields from objects?  What about existing instances?  What about pending destructors or finalizers? Etc.

There are many, many functionality details to attend to to make any kind of usuable EnC work.  Then there are many cross-tools integration issues necessary to provide the infrastructure to power EnC.  In particular, it helps to have some kind of repository of debug information that can make available the before- and after-edit debug information and object code to the debugger.  For C++, the incrementally updatable debug information in PDBs helps.  Incremental linking may help too.

Looking from the MS ecosystem over into the GCC ecosystem, it is easy to imagine the complexity and integration issues across GDB/GCC/binutils, the myriad of targets, some needed EnC specific target abstractions, and the "nice to have but inessential" nature of EnC, are why it has not appeared yet in GDB/GCC.

Happy hacking!

(p.s. It is instructive and inspiring to look at what the Smalltalk-80 interactive programming environment could do.  In St80 there was no concept of "restart" -- the image and its object memory were always live, if you edited any aspect of a class you still had to keep running.  In such environments object versioning was not a hypothetical.)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not familiar with MSVC's E&C, but GDB has some of the things you've mentioned:

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Altering.html#Altering

> **17. Altering Execution**
>
> Once you think you have found an error in your program, you might want to find out for certain whether correcting the apparent error would lead to correct results in the rest of the run. You can find the answer by experiment, using the gdb features for altering execution of the program.
>
> For example, you can store new values into variables or memory locations, give your program a signal, restart it at a different address, or even return prematurely from a function.
>
> **Assignment**: Assignment to variables
>   **Jumping**: Continuing at a different address
>   **Signaling**: Giving your program a signal
>   **Returning**: Returning from a function
>   **Calling**: Calling your program's functions
>   **Patching**: Patching your program
>   **Compiling and Injecting Code**: Compiling and injecting code in GDB

Comment: If I understand correctly, what E&C would be about is a convenient integration of gcc/g++ and the "patching" feature of gdb. I'm surprised that E&C is not common on gcc/gdb toolchain if gdb already supports a feature like patching.

Comment: In GDB parlance, "patching" is quite limited. It basically allows rewriting portions of the executable core while running, while providing none of the safeties needed for a true recompilation that Jan Gray pointed out in his excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty good reference to the old Apple implementation of "fix and continue". It also references other working implementations.

http://sources.redhat.com/ml/gdb/2003-06/msg00500.html

Here is a snippet:

> Fix and continue is a feature implemented by many other debuggers,
> which we added to our gdb for this release.  Sun Workshop, SGI ProDev
> WorkShop, Microsoft's Visual Studio, HP's wdb, and Sun's Hotspot Java
> VM all provide this feature in one way or another. I based our
> implementation on the HP wdb Fix and Continue feature, which they
> added a few years back.  Although my final implementation follows the
> general outlines of the approach they took, there is almost no shared
> code between them.  Some of this is because of the architectual
> differences (both the processor and the ABI), but even more of it is
> due to implementation design differences.

Note that this capability may have been removed in a later version of their toolchain.

UPDATE: Dec-21-2012
There is a [GDB Roadmap](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cauldron2012?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=jkratoch.pdf) PDF presentation that includes a slide describing "Fix and Continue" among other bullet points. The presentation is dated July-9-2012 so maybe there is hope to have this added at some point. The presentation was part of the [GNU Tools Cauldron 2012](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cauldron2012).

Also, I get it that adding E&C to GDB or anywhere in Linux land is a tough chore with all the different components.

But I don't see E&C as controversial. I remember using it in VB5 and VB6 and it was probably there before that. Also it's been in Office VBA since way back. And it's been in Visual Studio since VS2005. VS2003 was the only one that didn't have it and I remember devs howling about it. They intended to add it back anyway and they did with VS2005 and it's been there since. It works with C#, VB, and also C and C++. It's been in MS core tools for 20+ years, almost continuous (counting VB when it was standalone), and subtracting VS2003. But you could still say they had it in Office VBA during the VS2003 period ;)

And Jetbrains recently added it too their C# tool Rider. They bragged about it (rightly so imo) in their Rider blog.